# Errors when running npm install run

Tags: node.js

I have a github repo i want to run:
https://github.com/dappuniversity/price-bot

i did `git clone "above link"`
than `npm install` and i got those errors:
https://pastebin.com/HRBVAcKF

and when i ran
`npm run start i got those errors

```
> trading-bot@0.3.0 start /home/ether/Desktop/price-bot
> node index.js

Error: Mnemonic invalid or undefined
    at checkBIP39Mnemonic (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:74:15)
    at new HDWalletProvider (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:104:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/index.js:18:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! trading-bot@0.3.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the trading-bot@0.3.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ether/.npm/_logs/2020-07-16T20_51_12_835Z-debug.log
```

how can i fix those errors?

Answer (score 2):

The error is a bit cryptic because it originates from within a perhaps unfamiliar module. But this is why you get a stack trace. You merely need to look line by line to see the line in *your* code that originated the error.

```
at checkBIP39Mnemonic (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:74:15)
at new HDWalletProvider (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/node_modules/@truffle/hdwallet-provider/src/index.ts:104:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ether/Desktop/price-bot/index.js:18:23)
```

The `at Object.<anonymous>` line points to line 18 of `price-bot/index.js`, which is the main code you're trying to run, and is code you actually control, unlike the modules. So go to line 18 and you see:

```
// WEB3 CONFIG
const web3 = new Web3(new HDWalletProvider(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, process.env.RPC_URL) )
```

Based on the fact that the error says "Mnemonic invalid or undefined", I'm going to guess that either `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` or `process.env.RPC_URL` was undefined. On further inspection the code uses `dotenv`, as you can see at the very top:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

..which is a module that is responsible for filling out `process.env`. That those values are undefined means that you are probably missing a proper `.env` file in your project. I can see in the repository a `.env.example` which is clearly a template for the environment variables the project expects you to fill in:

```
RPC_URL="https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR_API_KEY"
PRIVATE_KEY="0x..."
ACCOUNT="0x..."
```

So all you need to do is rename `.env.example` to `.env` and then edit the contents, filling in the placeholder data with your actual private key, api key, etc.

Comment: ok, but when i create the file .env i dont see it anywhere, but it says in atom this file is already created

Comment: @bestethereumsites Configure your file browser to show hidden files.

Comment: the :env file was in gitignore when i removed the entry from gitignore the file showed up and i replaced all the content with api key etc; but i still get teh same error when running npm start run

Comment: @bestethereumsites Perform some basic debugging steps first, such as checking the values of `process.env.PRIVATE_KEY` and `process.env.RPC_URL` using `console.log`. If their values are not being set, your `.env` file is still not set up correctly. If their values are being set and you're receiving the same error, one of them simply must be invalid - like in the wrong format or copied the wrong thing.